# How retrieve number of last key pressed?

Tags: c#, keyboard

i am trying use e.KeyData, but it returns "NumPad2" or "D2" i want that return only "2", can use e.keycode or whatever.. Since it work, i already tried to convert to int and nothing works.

Comment: You are using the wrong event.  Mapping of virtual keys to actual typing characters is highly dependent on the active keyboard layout.  Use the KeyPress event instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string pressedKey = e.KeyData.ToString();

    if (pressedKey.StartsWith("D")) 
    { 
        pressedKey = pressedKey.Replace("D", "");
        MessageBox.Show(pressedKey);
    }

    if (pressedKey.StartsWith("NumPad"))
    { 
        pressedKey = pressedKey.Replace("NumPad", "");
        MessageBox.Show(pressedKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for that, i dont understand why C# dont have converter for that without have to adapt this..

Comment: No problem. There may be an easier way, but this should get you started atleast. Don't forget to accept the answer and vote up.

Comment: Done, voted up and accepted answer, sorry for make you wait, i am new user.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it appears that you either have to do something similar to what Rikki B suggested, or you can create a custom textbox and override the OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress like below:

First create custom event args:

```
public class CustomKeyEventArgs : KeyEventArgs
{
    public char LastCharPressed { get; set; }

    public CustomKeyEventArgs(Keys keyData, char lastCharPressed) : base(keyData)
    {
        LastCharPressed = lastCharPressed;
    }
}
```

Then set it up in the custom textbox:

```
    public delegate void CustomKeyUpHandler(object sender, CustomKeyEventArgs e);
    public event CustomKeyUpHandler OnCustomKeyUp;

    private char lastChar;
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        lastChar = e.KeyChar;
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(OnCustomKeyUp != null)
            OnCustomKeyUp(this, new CustomKeyEventArgs(e.KeyData, lastChar));
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
    }
```

Comment: last answer worked, how keys converter class work ? its possible make direct conversion without use ifs ? Thanks

Comment: I changed my answer as it was not doing what I expected. The above should work if you want to avoid a big if statement